# How to pass a parameter to a function convert?

Tags: extjs

```
    {
                        name: 'Surname',
                        type: 'string',

                         convert: function(v, record,val){
                            debugger
        //val -undefined...
                                    return record.get('Name') + 
' получает ' + v + ' рублей';
                                }
                    }
```

I want to pass a parameter to a function convert ..Its possible ?

```
person.get('Surname',47)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, according to the extjs documentation, the get function expect only one parameter, the field name,

But you can create another field that hold that information, and use it in the convert function,

```
convert: function(v, record,val){
   return record.get('Name') +  record.get('MyNewField')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand you want to bring formatting into the model. May it be better to use renderer in your view instead of data conversions? 
Using 'convert' has it's problems you should be aware of http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?175603-Don-t-use-convert()-as-a-getter-or-for-calculated-fields